The type com.formdev.flatlaf.FlatLightLaf is not accessible in java swing Eclipse IDE
Trying to create a java swing Desktop App using Flat Look and Feel, on Eclipse IDE. Don't have experience with Maven or Gradle so I decided to do it by: project > properties> java build path > classpath > add external jars > apply and close and then restarted eclipse and in the try-catch block added this:
    try {
        
        FlatLightLaf.setup();

        Frame frame = new Frame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
    }

     
     catch (Exception e) {
        
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e,"An Error occurred",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        System.err.println("\nAn Error interepted the normal flow of the program [Type: "+e+" ]\n");
        System.out.println("Details below: \n");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    

but get the error when I hover over import com.formdev.flatlaf.FlatLightLaf;
,the type com.formdev.flatlaf.FlatLightLaf is not accessible
I downloaded the jar from here: https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.formdev/flatlaf/3.4.1/jar?eh=
I did everything from re-downloading the jar to breaking down, but the errors don't go away

If you have a module-info.java file, delete it (if needed you can recreate it later via right-click on project and Configure) or in module-info.java add the required requires ...; statement. Otherwise, check if you can find the missing class in the Referenced Libraries node.
